# Reading BLOB data and injesting it into ElasticSearch using Logstash and Ruby filter

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, binary, logstash

I am trying to read a BLOB data stored in a Mysql table using JDBC connector in Logstash. I intend to index the data in Elasticsearch. I have been able to read a pdf file however when i read a Docx file, i get an error. I am using the following Ruby Code in the FILTER of Logstash:

```
file_to_read= StringIO.new(event.get('resume'))
#       THIS STATEMENT GIVE AN ERROR STRING CONTAINS A NULL BYTE            
            doc= Docx::Document.open (file_to_read)
                data=[]
#       Retrieve and display paragraphs
                doc.paragraphs.each do |p|
#       SINCE THE PARAGRAPHS ARE IN AN ARRAY, THE OUTPUT IS SENT TO AN ARRAY        
                    data<<p.text
#                   event.set('doc_content', data.to_s)
            end
```

If i write the binary string output from (event.get('resume')) to a file and then read it using doc= Docx::Document.open('FILE_TO_READ') then there is no error.

MY QUESTION:
Is it possible to directly read the binary string into Docx GEM as the documentation says it can read a Buffer also? Grateful for some pointers to the right way.
Thanks in advance